# Nested object in queryParams

Tags: ember.js

Question: How can I pass an object of type

```
query: {
  id: bla,
  email: bla-bla-bla
}
```

in queryParams?

Simple way like this

```
App.ArticlesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  queryParams: ['query'],
  query: {
    id: bla,
    email: bla-bla-bla
  }
});
```

does not work, of course :)

P.S. Sorry for bad english :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ember Query Parameters doesn't support setting an object as a QueryParam.  It only supports key-value pairs.  According to the [documentation](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/query-params/):

> Query parameters are optional key-value pairs that appear to the right
>   of the ? in a URL. For example, the following URL has two query
>   params, sort and page, with respective values ASC and 2:

If you're looking to bind both the `id` and `email` properties to the querystring vals, you'll have to specify it explicitly:

```
App.ArticlesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  queryParams: ['id, email'],
  id: null,
  email: null
});
```

If you really want to bind the `id` and `email` directly to a `query` object, you could setup an observer or computed property (depending on your goal) that observes a change in any of `id` or `email` properties and then updates some other object you have locally.

If you want to streamline this setup, you could consider using a Controller Mixin that defines a common set of properties in your queryParams plus a corresponding array.  Then you'd be able to do something like:

```
App.ArticlesController = Ember.ArrayController.extend( MyQueryParamsMixin, {
  queryParams: myQueryParams
  // The other properties would be set explicitly from your Mixin
  // Technically, you don't even need to declare the properties since they'll get bound anyway
  // thanks to queryParams, but it's good practice to let readers of your Mixin know which properties
  // are in use.
});
```

Comment: Perhaps, then, tell me, how do you make complex remote filters in Ember? And that remained meta.

Just, with the queryParams you would write in the address bar query like as

```?filters[parson][name]=Ivan&filters[person][age]=666```

and send a request to the ```store.findQuery```. Very simple!

Comment: There may be other ways to do this, but I always just bind to one queryParam property at a time, and then in my controller, I translate those properties into something more complex. E.g. `?filters[person][name]=Ivan` becomes `?name=Ivan`, then in my controller I know "Ivan"  will be bound to the `name` property. I could then use an observer or computed property to watch `name` and if it changes, update some other object. This kind of flexibility means that the "key-value pair" limitation is not really a limitation at all, since you can always observe any of the changed values.