# Is there an importable function to convert a javascript object to a query string?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is there a function I can import for converting a plain javascript hash/object into a query string?

So, here are the requirements:

- Cannot be based on jQuery (I need fastboot support)
- Must support nested objects & arrays.
- Must be built into Ember framework (no plugins)

I'm not really wanting to have another plugin dependency, since I know this is done internally in Ember.

**Update**
To clarify what I mean by nested:  an object with nested array or object properties will convert to the bracket syntax that Rails is familiar with:

`{my_values: [1,2]}  => ?my_values[]=1&my_values[]=2`

`{nested: {key: value}} => ?nested[key]=value`

Comment: Please check out this answer, it might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1714899/1370336

Comment: You can write the query sting then run the encodeURIComponet method to format it for use in the URL.

Comment: That's what [jQuery's $.param](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.param) does, you can easily rewrite that without dependencies on jQuery

Comment: Plan old JS works best. It's the least amount of dependencies. That a json object, it can have nested values, stringify it, then encode it for the URI

Comment: if there was a $.param function in Ember, that is what I would like.  I can't use jQuery in fastboot mode.

Comment: Isn't `JSON.stringify` solved it?

Comment: `JSON.stringify` turns the object into json, not querystring format.  example: `property=value&prop2=value2`

Answer (score 0):

This would do it:

```
function toQueryString (obj){
    var result =[];
    for(var i in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
            if(typeof obj[i] === "object") result.push(toQueryString(obj[i]))
            else result.push(encodeURIComponent(i) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[i]));
        }
    }
    return result.join("&");
}
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/9o4s5vjf/2/)

Edit: added recursion for nested objects

Comment: "Must support nested objects & arrays."

Not really sure what the asker means, but this solution definitely won't handle nested values.

Comment: Edited to recurse into nested objects... I'm assuming nested object properties are treated the same as top level properties

Comment: Thank you, but i'm looking for a function that exists already in Ember's framework that I could just import.  I know Ember makes this conversion internally with the controller & route queryParams object

Comment: I'm not super familiar with ember but this post would indicate that it is not possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264233/nested-object-in-queryparams

Comment: @Will P.  That's interesting.  So maybe the nested object isn't a requirement, but the array is.  Actually i'm wanting to send a query back to the rails api, so this isn't used in Ember's queryParams object.  Maybe the function doesn't exist in the framework.  In that case, i'll have to write my own...